# jquery timepicker wrong behaviour in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, google-chrome

Below is a jQuery Timepicker plugin which i am using in my project.

http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/
http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/jquery.timePicker.js

Working fine in other browsers but in Google chrome - once you click on the scrollbar and then click outside, the timepicker will not disappear.
This is because chrome is firing the **blur** event , when we click on the scrollbar whereas other browsers not firing when click on scrollbar.
Can anyone suggest a fix..
Thanx in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well nobody here replied..
I found a solution.
I have removed the blur event and instead used this...
[How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)
 it is working fine now..